# Magnetic forces and generators

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

i'm really struggling to break this question down into manageable chunks and identify which quantities are relevant. I'm also unsure of some of the wording in the question.

> A bar of length $20$$\mathrm{cm}$ and negligible mass can slide over two conducting rails connected to a DC generator producing an $\text emf$ of $V_{0} = 6V$, connected so as to produce a current as in the figure. The resistance of the bar is $R = 0.08$$\mathrm{Ω}$, all other parts have negligible resistance. The bar is connected through a pully to a body of mass $1.2$$\mathrm{kg}$ the system is immersed in a uniform magnetic field orthogonal to the rails, as in the figure, whose magnitude is $1$$\mathrm{T}$. The system is designed in such a way that, after a while, the body is pulled upward with a constant limiting speed.
>   Compute:
>
> a) The current flowing in the circuit and the power provided by the dc generator when the limiting speed is reached.
>
> b) The magnitude of the limiting speed.
>
> c) The value of the resistance of the bar corresponding to which the body does not move at all.

I do not know what 'limiting speed' means, I have searched online and through my text book to no avail. I think if I had a clear picture of what that was, i'd be able to make some progress.

At a guess;

$EMF = VBL$

$V = \frac{EMF}{BL}$ = $30$ $\mathrm{ms^{-1}}$ Is this the limiting speed?

When the bar is stationary (or if there was no magnetic field?), the current in the circuit could be found easily via ohm's law. $I = \frac{V}{R} = \frac{6}{0.08} = 75 \mathrm{A}$

I feel like i'm going round in circles if I say that the bar is moving so there should be an induced current in the bar. I think that would violate conservation of energy, since it would keep getting faster and faster.

So I think it's correct to say that a current of 75 Amps makes the bar move at 30 meters per second and likewise, if you were to move the bar at 30 meters per second, you would induce a current of 75 Amps.

I don't know if my reasoning makes sense up to this point, but I don't know how to take it much further.

I'd really appreciate a helping hand,

thanks!

Jacob.

Comment: I think what they mean is something like a 'terminal velocity' where all the forces add up and you accelerate no more.

Comment: As for your question, it has to do with magnetic flux; the 'loop' area is changing, but the field is constant.

Comment: I don't think there is a loop... With regards to your first comment, is a good way to approach this to find the current passing through the wire to produce a magnetic force equal to the weight applied?

Comment: The sliding bar is part of the circuit yes? If it slides, doesn't that mean the size of the circuit is changing?

Comment: Yes, I see what you're saying, but the question only provides information about one length of wire. I don't think there is enough information to tackle it like that.

Comment: For the induced emf, you don't need to know how large the area is. You only need to know how fast it is changing.

Comment: I don't know how to do that. Your first comment inspired me to do this; Equate the magnetic force with the weight and solve for the current that must be flowing in the wire to produce that force.

From there, using ohm's law to find the voltage, I can use P=IV to find the power supplied. Which I think completes part a.

Comment: Imagine there is no power source and ignore the weight, but the field is still there. What happens when you move the bar?